# ffmpeg concat 2 videos and fit the first video to the resolution of the second video

Tags: ffmpeg

I have videos I want to add an intro on, the videos vary by resolution and aspect ratio, I want to add an intro at the very start of the videos that fits to the main video's size, how do I do it in FFMPEG.

Comment: Do you want to do this manually by typing the command or from a script?

Comment: Look for [scale2ref](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-scale2ref) filter.

Comment: i want to do it from the command line

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?